# What is the difference between including a file directly and linking against it?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-functions

I found these lines in a header file (https://github.com/eyalroz/printf/blob/master/src/printf/printf.h) that is part of a `printf` implementation.

```
// If you want to include this implementation file directly rather than
// link against, this will let you control the functions' visibility,
// e.g. make them static so as not to clash with other objects also
// using them.
#ifndef PRINTF_VISIBILITY
#define PRINTF_VISIBILITY
#endif
```

Then it proceeds to put that label before every function declaration.

```
PRINTF_VISIBILITY
int  sprintf_(char* s, const char* format, ...) ATTR_PRINTF(2, 3);
PRINTF_VISIBILITY
int vsprintf_(char* s, const char* format, va_list arg) ATTR_VPRINTF(2);
```

I know that "link against" means doing something like

```
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o printf.o -c printf.c
gcc main.o printf.o -o output
```

But what does the other option "include file directly" mean? What would be the gcc commands in this case?

Also, if there are other objects (which I think it means object files) using the functions, why make them static in the first place and how could they clash? How could, for example, `main.c` use these functions if they are static?

Comment: The link may point to a different file in some future, the direct link does not. The point is when changes are made. With the direct link, changes are on that very file. In the case of a link, the link will point to a totally different file and whatever happens to the previous file, improvements, changes, damages ... will not be seen in your application.

Comment: Putting that label before every function declaration does not control inclusion. If the label was `#define`d (as nothing) then it's a no-op. If it isn't the compiler errors with an undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what does the other option "include file directly" mean?

I take that to mean *source* inclusion, via an `#include` directive.

> What would be the gcc commands in this case?

It would normally be a matter of source code, not GCC options, but GCC does have an `-include` option that could be used for the purpose.

> Also, if there are other objects (which I think it means object files)

Yes, other object files, though from a C language perspective the key concept is other *translation units*.

> using the functions, why make them static in the first place and how could they clash?

If you have two different translation units contributing to the same program, and they both provide definitions of the same function, and more than one of those definitions has external linkage, then you have a collision between conflicting external function definitions. (The colliding definitions being lexically identical is irrelevant.)  Declaring the functions with the `static` keyword gives them internal linkage instead of external.  Each such definition can be referenced by other functions in the same translation unit, but not by functions from other translation units.  Internal function definitions from different translation units do not clash.

> How could, for example, `main.c` use these functions if they are static?

`main.c` *having `#include`d static definitions of these functions*, any function in the translation unit can call the included functions normally.  Nothing special is required, other than the inclusion of the function sources (which is a bit weird).  The usual requirements for having in-scope declarations apply, of course, but typically that would be taken care of simply by performing the inclusion near the top of the source file.

As for the `PRINTF_VISIBILITY` macro, the idea is that if you were using `#include "printf.c"`, then you might want to first `#define PRINTF_VISIBILITY static` so that you get static function definitions. If that macro is not otherwise defined, then the file defines it to expand to nothing, so that you get external definitions.